# How to calculate the sum of virtual fields

Tags: qgis

I have a set of data on track creation in a large forest, my job is to explore the cost implications of various layouts. I have a virtual field for track length and one which multiplies length by cost per metre to give total cost for that track. What I then need is some means of checking the total cost of the entire track network (the whole layer).
Using Statist seems to come up with all zeros, Group Stats won't calculate virtual fields, I've tried creating real fields which mimic the virtual ones, but then they won't update when I alter the polylines.
I can't believe I'm the only one to encounter such a requirement, but I can't seem to find a solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AutoFields](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/) plugin for that.

Just add an AutoField for keeping length up-to-date and another one to calculate track cost. Watch [this video](http://viemo.com/germap/autofields-area-population-density) for a related example.

AutoFields store calculated values into your data, so they will be recognized by the plugins you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the statistics panel which is core functionality.

Choose the layer and the virtual field and see all kind of statistics. Among them sum.

[image]